# CFL Condition of general Finite Difference Scheme

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

I need to find the CFL Condition of the following Finite Difference Scheme.

$$
u_t + cu_x = 0\\
u_{j+1,m} = Au_{j,m+3} + Bu_{j,m+2} + Cu_{j,m+1} + Du_{j,m} + Eu_{j,m-1}
$$
So far I have the following work:

$$
\left(\frac{u_{j+1,m}-Du_{j,m}}{\Delta t}\right) + c\left(\frac{Au_{j,m+3}-Eu_{j,m-1}}{4\Delta x}\right) = 0\\
u_{j+1,m} = \frac{c\Delta t}{4\Delta x}\left(Eu_{j,m-1}-Au_{j,m+3}\right)+Du_{j,m}\\
u_{j+1,m} = \frac{\sigma}{4}\left(Eu_{j,m-1}-Au_{j,m+3}\right)+Du_{j,m}\\
0 \leq \left|\frac{c\Delta t}{4\Delta x}\right| \leq 1\\
0 \leq \left|\frac{c\Delta t}{\Delta x}\right| \leq 4
$$
[image: Numerical Domain of Dependence]

I have drawn out the Domain of dependence in the image above and solved the CFL condition to be $0 \leq \left|\sigma = \frac{c\Delta t}{\Delta x}\right| \leq 4$, but I do not think this answer is correct. What did I do incorrectly? Is the CFL condition supposed to be a value of 4 on both sides of the domain of dependence from $m$ even though it goes up to $m+3$ but only down to $m-1$?

**EDIT:** Is the following the correct way to solve this?

$$
x_{m-1} \leq x_m-ct_{j+1} \leq x_{m+3}\\
-\Delta x\leq -c\Delta t \leq 3\Delta x\\
\boxed{-1 \leq \frac{-c\Delta t}{\Delta x} \leq 3}
$$

where the boxed solution is the CFL condition.

Comment: @EditPiAf If taking the derivatives of the scheme with respect to t and x and plugging them into the given equation is not correct, then what should my next steps be from here? I am not sure how to proceed to find the actual solution to the CFL condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 3 equations of OP's attempt modify the expression of the scheme $$
u_{j+1,m} = Au_{j,m+3} + Bu_{j,m+2} + Cu_{j,m+1} + Du_{j,m} + Eu_{j,m-1} \, . \tag{1}
$$
A simple comparison with the above time-stepping formula shows that they aren't equivalent. One shouldn't "take the derivatives of the scheme with respect to $t$ and $x$" as proposed in comments to OP.

You may have a read at Sec. 1.6 p. 34 of the book by J.C. Strikwerda, *Finite Difference Schemes and Partial Differential Equations* (SIAM). You are expected to prove something similar to the Theorem 1.6.1 therein:

**Theorem.** *For the explicit difference scheme (1) for the advection equation $u_t+cu_x=0$ with $\Delta t/\Delta x = \lambda$ held constant, a necessary condition for stability is the Courant-Friedrichs-Lewy (CFL) condition $$ \sigma = |c\lambda| \leq \sigma_\max .  $$* And the goal is to find the optimal value of the critical Courant number $\sigma_\max$ such that the above property is true. Note that the Theorem 1.6.1 of the book corresponds to the case $A=B=0$, for which $\sigma_\max = 1$. Comparing the numerical and physical domains of dependence looks like a good strategy to solve it. Keep in mind that $c$ has arbitrary sign (a priori), and that (LeVeque, 2002, p. 69)

**CFL Condition:** *A numerical method can be convergent only if its numerical domain of dependence contains the true domain of dependence of the PDE, at least in the limit as $\Delta t$ and $\Delta x$ go to zero.*